# Swift - How to open excel app with resource excel file within the project? (Can't open file Error)

Tags: ios, swift, excel

So I have created a loan calculator that generates a bunch of information plus a Amortization Table. I want to add a feature to create a Amortization Table on Excel.

So my plan is to have a button to open excel using a resource excel file I have in my project.

I'm using this pod to write to the excel file

https://cocoapods.org/pods/XlsxReaderWriter

I followed this guide and everything seems to work fine.

https://github.com/joelparkerhenderson/demo_swift_excel_xlsx_reader_writer

I believe the problem lies on the lines of code that open the excel file

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if indexPath.section == 3
        {
            if indexPath.row == 0
            {
                let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AmortizationTable", ofType: "xlsx")!
                let urlString: String = "ofe|u|" + path
                let encodedString = urlString.addingPercentEncoding(withAllowedCharacters: .urlQueryAllowed)
                let encodedURLString = "ms-excel:" + encodedString! //+ "|n|AmortizationTable.xlsx|a|App"

                if let url = URL(string: encodedURLString), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(url) {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(url)
                } else if let itunesUrl = NSURL(string: "https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/microsoft-excel/id586683407?mt=8&uo=4"), UIApplication.shared.canOpenURL(itunesUrl as URL) {
                    UIApplication.shared.openURL(itunesUrl as URL)
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

I also have this function to be called when the user calculates. It works fine but I thought I should add it in.

```
func createExcel() {
        // Set the path to the path of wherever you put your Excel file.
        // The path in this demo code is the path to the demo.xlsx file.
        let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AmortizationTable", ofType: "xlsx")!

        // Open the spreadsheet, get the first sheet, first worksheet, and first cell A1.
        // This is solely demo code to show basics; your actual code would do much more here.
        let spreadsheet: BRAOfficeDocumentPackage = BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.open(path)
        let sheet: BRASheet = spreadsheet.workbook.sheets[0] as! BRASheet
        let worksheet: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets[0] as! BRAWorksheet
        let cell: BRACell = worksheet.cell(forCellReference: "A1")
        cell.value = "It's working!"
        spreadsheet.save()
        // Print some info to show the code works.
        print(cell.value) // print "It's working"
        print(cell.stringValue()) // print "Alpha"
    }
```

When I click the button, It will transfer to the excel app and I get this error:

[image: Excel Error]

Comment: I'm guessing what's happening is that ms-excel doesn't have access to open the path you're giving it, since that path is within your application's bundle.

Comment: @Daniel Espina did you find the solution?

Comment: @Spydy Yes! Sorry for the late reply. I'll comb through my code and post my solution

Comment: @Spydy I posted my solution. I hope this will help. Sorry for the delay. Let me know if you have any questions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry everyone for the year long late reply. Here's my entire function as of today.

```
func createExcel(amortizationArray: [amortizationObject], loanName: String) -> Date
    {
    // Post notification that createExcel has started
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: .isStart, object: nil)

    // Set the path to the path of wherever you put your Excel file.
    let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AmortizationTable", ofType: "xlsx")!

    // Open the spreadsheet, get the first sheet, first worksheet, and first cell A1.
    let spreadsheet: BRAOfficeDocumentPackage = BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.open(path)
    let worksheetToCopy: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets[0] as! BRAWorksheet
    let worksheetName = "Amortization Table"
    let worksheet: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.createWorksheetNamed(worksheetName, byCopying: worksheetToCopy)

    var cell: BRACell
    for i in 0..<amortizationArray.count
    {
        let amortObj = amortizationArray[i]

        var color: UIColor
        if  amortObj.shade
        {
            color = UIColor(rgb: 0xf9f9f9)
        }
        else
        {
            color = UIColor(rgb: 0xf2f2f2)
        }
        cell = worksheet.cell(forCellReference: ("A" + String(describing: (i+2))), shouldCreate: true)

        cell.setCellFillWithForegroundColor(color, backgroundColor: .white, andPatternType: kBRACellFillPatternTypeDarkTrellis)

        let period = amortObj.amortiaztionValuesArray[0]
        let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
        dateFormatter.dateStyle = .short
        dateFormatter.locale = Locale.current

        if let date = Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .month, value: Int(period), to: Date()) {
            let value = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
            cell.setStringValue(value)
        }
        let cellColumns = ["B", "C", "D","E","F","G"]

        for j in 0..<cellColumns.count
        {
            let column = cellColumns[j]
            cell = worksheet.cell(forCellReference: (column + String(describing: (i+2))), shouldCreate: true)
            let value = currencyInput(index: j+1, amortObj: amortObj)
            cell.setStringValue(value)
            cell.setCellFillWithForegroundColor(color, backgroundColor: .white, andPatternType: kBRACellFillPatternTypeDarkTrellis)
        }
    }

    var paths: Array = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as Array

    let fullPath: String = paths[0] + "/" + loanName + ".xlsx"
    spreadsheet.workbook.removeWorksheetNamed("Sheet1")
    spreadsheet.save(as: fullPath)

    let date = Date()
    UserDefaults.standard.set(fullPath, forKey: String(describing: date))

    return date
}
```

The most important piece of information I believe is this snippet of code here.

```
// Set the path to the path of wherever you put your Excel file.
    let path: String = Bundle.main.path(forResource: "AmortizationTable", ofType: "xlsx")!

    // Open the spreadsheet, get the first sheet, first worksheet, and first cell A1.
    let spreadsheet: BRAOfficeDocumentPackage = BRAOfficeDocumentPackage.open(path)
    let worksheetToCopy: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.worksheets[0] as! BRAWorksheet
    let worksheetName = "Amortization Table"
    let worksheet: BRAWorksheet = spreadsheet.workbook.createWorksheetNamed(worksheetName, byCopying: worksheetToCopy)
```

Be sure to delete the empty worksheet once you save

```
var paths: Array = NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(.documentDirectory, .userDomainMask, true) as Array

let fullPath: String = paths[0] + "/" + loanName + ".xlsx"
spreadsheet.workbook.removeWorksheetNamed("Sheet1")
spreadsheet.save(as: fullPath)
```

Let me know if this helped anyone. I'll answer any questions

Comment: Thank you very much for the solution. I am facing issue opening xlsx file in Microsoft Excel iPad app. I will check if i can use XlsxReaderWriter.

Comment: @Spydy No problem! Let me know if you need any help